# Проблема с прорисовкой окна браузера

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

При ресайзе браузера или же при разворачивания на полный экран контент сайта ресайзится с задержкой (видно черный фон а потом через полсекунды контент перерисовывается). может кто нибудь сталкивался с этим. Что делать?

Comment: У вас повешены на ресайз окна события? Возможно связано с большим количеством расчетов в событии `window.onresize`

Comment: Видел такой глюк в некоторых версиях FireFox под OS X. В какиех браузерах / ОС воспроизводится эта ситуация? Проверяли ли на разных устройствах?

Comment: воспроизводится эта ситуация даже в Chrome, но я пишу на angular js приложения, которое использует какой то "WebEngine Fancy Browser". Насчет window.onresize то да в проекте подключенные bootstrap и jQuery + куча плагинов - там много ресайзов. но без них надо все переписывать, может есть какие то настройки браузера?

Comment: А почему ты считаешь, что это ненормально? Сейчас попробовал быстро менять размер окна в яндекс-браузере - такое происходит на всех сайтах.

Comment: Ну клиент всегда прав, ему это не понравилось, надо как то решить, но кстати window.onresize ни при чем, я поставили пустой HTML с черным бекграундом это воспроизводится также.

Comment: @ІванЦуркан: Простите, но Ваш вопрос напоминает анекдоты про пользователя, который звонит в поддержку и ругается, что у него черный экран. После пяти минут разговора выясняется, что он не включил свой компьютер. К Вашей проблемме: нужно иметь хотя бы отдаленное представление о Вашем сайте, чтобы начать гадать о возможной причине, так как возможнах причин - тысячи. Никто не может помочь решить проблемму, сформулированную как «моя программа не работает, как мне мадо. Помогите исправить ошибку». Невозможно помочь, если нет каких-либо деталей в вопросе и если читает вопрос не экстрасенс. Извините.

Comment: Возможно я не правильно сформулировал вопрос, признаюсь первый раз пишу на форуме, но в комментах я дописывал и объяснил ситуацию, вроде меня даже поняли и что то пытались ответить, если кто то не понял извините.

Comment: Изменить фон на белый)))))))))))

Comment: Меньше нагрузку на обрабюотчик. Запустите консоль, напишите тестер на время. По результатам можно будет сказать, в какой части сайт перенагружен.. Соответственно, придется уменьшать код, убирать кучу плагинов и т.д... Либо, менять хостинг на более производительный. Проблем, конечно может быть много, но в данном случае, скорее всего, из-за перенагрузки на странице.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал меньше нагрузку на обрабюотчик + убрал фон, сделал белый, теперь по крайней мере не так заметно когда перерисовывается